# How to cancel BackgroundWorker and set IsBusy to false?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I am trying to cancel a background worker in WinForms with `CancelAsync()` but this isn't setting the `IsBusy` property of the worker to false.

The function that closes the worker is meant to restart the worker after doing some work. To do this, I use the `IsBusy` property to check if the worker has closed before starting it again.

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        buttonStart.Enabled = false;
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        // Does some work
    }
}

private void buttonRestart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation && backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        buttonStart.Enabled = true;
    }

    // Do some work
    // ...

    if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)    // Worker is busy here
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

---

### Update

After much troubleshooting and debugging, I could not find a direct solution to the problem above.

I did however find that BGW is quite outdated (first released with .Net 2.0), it has become somewhat obsolete and has been mostly replaced by Task/await. I was able to port my code over from the background worker to an async task and it now works and behaves as expected.

Comment: Are you trying to cancel the work represented in your example with three dots `...` in a non-cooperative manner? How long does it take for each `...` work to complete?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes. `...` is a process that can take upwards to 30 seconds, so I would like to be able to exit/close the thread midway through the process.

Comment: In this case you are in a sad situation, because part of your program has to fight against another part. Programs are not supposed to work this way. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77229683/how-to-cancel-a-task-without-passing-a-cancellationtokensource-in-net/77230794#77230794) for ideas, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75087774/thread-or-task-stopping-a-hung-single-line-of-code/75090418#75090418).

Comment: `// Process that can take upwards to 30 seconds` is going to need to support cooperative canncellation,  you can't arbitrarily cancel a running thread.

Comment: Do NOT ever use `Application.DoEvents()`. It is evil incarnate!

Answer (score 1):

`BackgroundWorker` has a [`CancellationPending` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending) that, as its name suggests, returns `true` if cancellation has been signalled by calling the `CancelAsync` method. You can use this property in combination with `IsBusy` to achieve what you want.